# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name Returns wrong user name

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

It is a Plain **ASP.NET** application using **SQL Membership Provider** for authentication. While application runs good most of the time. We have recently seeing complains from users saying they are seeing other users account.

I am pretty sure & confirmed again I directly consume **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name** in the code to get user information. So under heavy load I get different user name returned.

Has anyone faced similar issue ? Have possible cause ?

Application Runs in ASP.NET 4.0, Web Forms , No caching ,Not handled any cookies in code, no Javascripts that is sniffing cookies.

I see these two links taking about same but no answers posted.

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/324385-serious-issue-httpcontext-current-user-identity-name

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Miscellaneous/Q_21105924.html

Comment: Please describe your application a bit more.  Do you use any custom caching (and thus perhaps capture one user's data or .ASPXAUTH response cookie in the cache and serve it out to subsequent visitors)?  If you run Windows Update on the server, does it show that you are fully patched?  What version of ASP.NET?  And so on..

Comment: Updated the answer, I will check for updates in the server.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? If so, how?

Comment: hi, I have the same problem , did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

Forms Authentication shouldn't be related to Membership provider too much.

FormsAuthentication saves signed user information into `.ASPXAUTH` cookie. And when next request comes to server, it decrypts cookie value and set it back to `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. It uses MachineKey for encryption\decription. Then it creates FormsIdentity object based on `FormsAuthenticationTicket` object that holds username. So, your userName is stored on client. And whole this process doesn't include usage of Membership provider.

Forms Authentication uses Membership only when you do login for user, and then based on logged in user FormsAuthentication creates a cookie with UserName.

About your problem, you need to check `.ASPXAUTH` cookie value for those requests who has invalid UserName. You can try to log cookie information for these bad requests, and then you can decrypt them to get userName info from request. Or if you can reproduce it locally you can disable Forms cookie encryption ([protection element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and then check it's value for bad requests

Comment: I dont get, How could It return a random person's email id ? I am trying to reproduce this problem but no luck yet. I know this happens on a rare case, I have seen screen shots of user sending me an account that is not theirs and no way related?.

Comment: It shouldn't be random. You need to check cookie values for these request, maybe some JavaScript in your application overwrites\deletes cookie values, and then Asp.Net just uses empty UserName as there is no cookie for it.

Comment: How do I check cookie value for these request ? Is there a logging option ? I know it is strange, but there is no other Javascript is handling cookie. It is a small application, I ran through it. I made sure myself I use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name at all places.

Comment: You can get them from HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"]. If you can reproduce it locally you can also use Asp.Net Trace mechanism - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(v=vs.85).aspx . It will record local request and you can see them on `trace.axd` page